# Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games and elementary equivalence: is it possible to remove the relations-only constraint?

Tags: model-theory

How do you generalize Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games beyond relational theories, assuming that the signature is finite?

The [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game#Definition) of an Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game restricts attention to relational signatures.

In David Marker's *A Shorter Model Theory*, some additional constraints are given. Namely, given a finite relational language $L$ and models $M$ and $N$, $M$ is elementarily equivalent to $N$ if and only if the $n$-move EF game is a win for Duplicator for all $n$. (Paraphrased from Theorem 2.4.6 on page 53).

I'm curious if there's a generalization of this result that drops the "relations only" constraint, but keeps the finite language constraint.

For each turn pair $t_i$, Spoiler picks an element of $A$ or an element of $B$ and then  Duplicator picks an element of the other structure.

The turn pairs can be thought of as producing $A'$ and $B'$, where the domain of each is limited to items picked during the game. If the shared signature of $A$ and $B$ has no function or relation symbols, restricting the domains of $A$ and $B$ like this works, since there's no danger of $A'$ or $B'$ *failing to be closed under the interpretation of constant or relation symbols*.

---

One strategy that seems somewhat straightforward is *paraphrasing away* constants and variables in order to produce a new signature and a new theory.

Replace each constant $c$ with a unary predicate $P(x)$ and add the sentence $\exists! x \mathop. P(x)$ to the theory.

Replace each $n$-ary function $f$ with an $(n+1)$-ary predicate $P(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ and all the sentence $\forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_n \mathop. \exists! x_{n+1} \mathop. P(x_1, \cdots, x_n, x_{n+1})$.

However, I'm not sure that *this strategy preserves the intended victory conditions for the Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game*.

Comment: See this question and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1533396/7062 Do you think your question is a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, it's the same question. I didn't see it because it doesn't contain the string `"Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes - it is possible to save the EF game theorem

No - it doesn't immediately works and requires some modifications

---

First let's redefine the game: instead of looking on the 2 sequences $a=(a_0,a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ and $b=(b_0,b_1,...,b_{n-1})$, we will look at the closure of those 2 sequences, and similarly instead of looking for (partial) embedding $h:a\to b$, we will look at a (partial) embedding between the 2 substructures such that $h(a_i)=b_i$

---

Let $N=(|N|, s, 0)$ be the standard model of arithmetic, and let $M=(|M|, S, 0)$ be such that $N\prec M$, $|N|\subset |M|$, $0^N=0^M$(we will just use $0$) and $s(x)=S(x)$ for all $x$ in $|N|$.

Now let $h:N\to M$ be embedding, if $c\in|M|$ is non standard, then $c\notin f''|N|$(*)

> Claim: $N\equiv M$ but in the generalized version of EF game, the spoiler always has winning strategy, regardless of the length of the game

Proof: let the spoiler choose a non standard element of $|M|$, then the duplicator must choose an element from $|N|$, let the rest of the game continue (it doesn't matter what each of the player choose from now on)

Let $A$, $B$ be the closure of the sequences of element the player chose from $N$ and $M$ respectively, notice that $A=N$ (as every element of $|N|$ can be constructed using a finite formula with 0 parameters using only $0$ and $s$)

If the duplicator won, then there is a partial embedding $h:N\to B$ such that $h(x_0)$ is non standard, but by (*) we can't have a non standard element in the range of $h$.

---

Before explaining how to save the EF game theorem, let's notice what went wrong.

In the usual version, if the duplicator wins on $n$ steps game, then (and only then) the 2 structure are elementary equivalent for statements with $n$ quantifiers.

When we add a function symbol, to represent it as a relation symbol *we are adding quantifiers*.

More specifically, if $M$ is a model with language that contains function symbols, and $M'$ is the model $M$ after replacing each function symbol with relations symbol+the axioms of the relation symbols being functional, then if $\phi$ is an $M-$formula, then the equivalent $M'-$formual, $\phi'$ **will have more quantifiers** (usually).

So we can save our theorem now:

Instead of counting quantifiers, count $m(\phi)$ where, $m$ on a variable is $0$, $m$ on a constant is $1$, $m(\lnot\phi)=m(\phi), m(\phi\lor \psi)=\max(\phi,\psi),m(\exists x\phi)=m(\phi)+1$, and lastly, if $c_0$ to $c_{n-1}$ are terms then:

$$m(f(c_0,...,c_{n-1}))=1+m(c_0)+...+m(c_1), m(c_0=c_1)=\max(m(c_0)+m(c_1)-1, 0)$$.

This function $m$ adds to our usual counting the "price of unnesting" each formula

---

I *believe* the modified version of the game is due to Hodges